# MySQL Update after N rows

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, sql-update, limit

I need to  update a table  except its top 1000 records. My query is like this :

```
UPDATE tableA 
SET price = 100 
WHERE price = 200 AND
      item_id =12 AND 
      status NOT IN (1,2,3);
```

I know the subquery approcah will work here but I am having a huge table in which 200000 records satisfy the `WHERE` condition and it is growing. So I think if I follow the sub query approach, it will will not scale as the DB grows.

Also I have seen specifying `LIMIT` in `UPDATE` query but it is up to a certain limit. In my case it is after a certain offset and should update all the records.

Also it is possible to find the total count and specify it with LIMIT. But the `COUNT()` query is  failing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use user defined variable:

```
SET @X = (SELECT ID FROM tableA 
    WHERE price = 200 AND item_id =12 AND status NOT IN (1,2,3) 
    ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1000,1 );
UPDATE tableA SET price = 100 
    WHERE price = 200 AND item_id =12 AND status NOT IN (1,2,3) 
    AND ID>@X;
```

Yes, you will need some way how to define "what is first N rows". User defined variables gives you just more options how to do it. And If you can not do it effectively in some select query, you will need to think about some way how to rework such table. Maybe different indexing approach, splitting the table, caching some values, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would be a right solution but if you have a unique `ID` column in your table; lets say `ID` for example then you can place the predicate very easily saying `WHERE ID > 1000`. Which will consider only rows from 1001th position like

```
UPDATE tableA SET price = 100 
WHERE price = 200 
AND item_id = 12
AND ID > 1000
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul for the quick reply.  but I can't rely on ID here as it is selecting for a specific item and so IDs might not be in an order.

Comment: with `ID` I mean, a unique auto_increment like column. then the above solution is the most efficient one. else it's bit tedious when comes to huge load.

Comment: Yeah. I also meant the same :)

Comment: LOL ... then you are almost screwed up. BTW, how you determine `top 1000 records`. is it just top 1000 rows (OR) they have to satisfy some condition.